# String Cloud Stream - How to force a message to be dead-lettered without requeing if retry is enabled?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Spring Cloud Stream and we have retry enabled using maxAttempts > 1 in our consumer. Is there any way to force a message to send immediately to a DLQ, i.e. to bypass the requeuing e.g. throwing a special exception in the consumer listener when the message is processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retry policy in the binder supports that but it's not currently exposed to be configurable.

This is one of a number of exception handling improvement stories we are starting to work on.

Comment: Do you have an issue number for that - that we can observer the progress?

Comment: Yes, it's [#915](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/915), specifically but #913 and #914 are also part of the overall effort.